# Select a row based on the value of another row

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

**App goal**

Send messages from retailers to registered customers mobile via GCM

**DB architecture**

I have a `customers` table and a related `customers_realtions` table with the following fields: `id`, `customerID`, `retailerID`, `isBlocked`

**Required outcome**

A customer can register for a specific retailer, or for a wildcard (all of them).

In case one registers for all the retailers, he has an option to block a specific retailer from sending future messages, effectively creating a blacklist.

**DB values for each status**

1. When a customer registers for a single retailer `retailerID` is assigned with the retailer ID.
2. When a customer register for all of the retailers `retailerID` equals 1.
3. When a customer blocks a retailer there are two options:

   a. if he registered to this specific retailer before the `isBlocked` field is updated to 1 (true)

   b. if he registered to all retailers before a new row is created for this retailer and `isBlocked` is set to 1 (true)

**The challenge**

When sending the message the SELECT query should include the customers that has a retailerID of 1 and *does not* have the sending `retailerID` when `isBlocked` equals 1.

For example, in this situation

```
id  customerID  retailID    isBlocked
129 46          111                 1
128 46          1                   0
```

I don't want the customer to be selected even if the retailerID is 111

**My attempt**

```
SELECT * FROM customers_relations 
              WHERE 
                (retailID=111 
              OR 
                (retailID=1
                AND 
                (SELECT isBlocked FROM `customers_relations` WHERE customerID=46 AND retailID=111)=0))
              AND
                NOT isBlocked
```

**Question**

While this is working for a single customer for whom I know the ID in advance, I am struggling to figure a way of writing a similar query for multiple customers.

Comment: What happens if a user blocks and unblocks a retailer multiple times?  How many rows get created?

Comment: obviously the row is created only if the user didn't register to this specific retailer before, i.e if he registered for all the retailers. In case he did register for a specific retailer, the value of `isBlocked` is just updated accordingly.

Comment: . . Look at step (3) in your description of how the system works.  It explicitly says that a new row is created when a retailer is blocked.  That's why I asked the question.  The first query in my answer should then be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of this as an aggregation query. You want to look through all the rows that are not blocked for a customer and determine whether retailer 111 is available or all retailers are available:

```
SELECT customerId
FROM customers_relations cr
WHERE isBlocked = false
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING MAX(retailId = 111) > 0 OR
       MAX(retailId = 1) > 0;
```

I notice that your question actually says that a *new* row is created in `customer_relations` when someone is blocked.  The above assumes there is one row.  To handle the case when a block on any row would cause a block, then:

```
SELECT customerId
FROM customers_relations cr
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING (MAX(retailId = 111) > 0 OR
        MAX(retailId = 1) > 0
       ) AND
       MAX(retailId = 111 AND isblocked = true) = 0;
```